# Permission Check for SET_ALARM always returns PERMISSION_DENIED without asking user for permission in Android Studio, Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to set an alarm for my app in Android Studio using `Kotlin`. However, running `alarmManager.setRepeating(...)`, doesn't work and `alarmManager.nextAlarmClock` returns null. I've found that when I try to check for `SET_ALARM` permission I get `PERMISSION_DENIED` (-1), even though I've specified using it in the manifest. `ActivityCompat.requestPermission` won't open the alert so the user is not able to grant permission. How can I get my app to allow `SET_ALARM`? Code below:

```
val permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.SET_ALARM)
    if(permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("Notification", "Permission not granted earlier, permission: $permissionCheck")
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf<String>(android.Manifest.permission.SET_ALARM),1)
    } else {
        Log.d("Notification", "Permission was already granted")
    }


    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

    val intent = Intent(this, NotificationReceiver::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,Values.ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    val alarmManager = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent)
    Log.d("Norif", "Notifications set: ${alarmManager.nextAlarmClock}")
```

and Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


<application>
<receiver android:name="NotificationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.tester.alarmmanager"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: `SET_ALARM` is listed as a Normal Permission, for which the following applies: _"If an app declares in its manifest that it needs a normal permission, the system automatically grants the app that permission at install time. The system does not prompt the user to grant normal permissions, and users cannot revoke these permissions."_

Comment: That doesn't seem to work since I declare in my manifest that I need the permission, and still the Permission Check returns -1, which I believe is Permission Denied... Any ideas what might cause this? I've tried on several devices and emulators, and not even Android Developers sample alarm project works. Could there be some settings that are blocking it for me?